# how to send two models includes data to ajax success call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models called `User` and `post`. now am calling controller action through ajax. Now i want to send `User.includes(:posts)` data to ajax success function. Am successfully sending data also. But in ajax success function am able to see only users data but not posts data.

```
            $.each(data,function(k,v) {
                $('#testDataTable tbody').append('<tr><td>'+v.id+'</td><td>'+v.name+'</td></tr>');
            });
```

Am trying `v.posts` but its saying `undfined` . How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

In Controller My code is

```
@e = Master.find(params[:id]) 
@data = @e.users.includes(:posts)
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @data}
end
```

Comment: can u add the lines how your send your data from controller action to ajax

Comment: I have updated my question please check

Comment: console the data in your browser and please check whether you are calling right `v.posts`

Comment: No luck i tried that

Answer (score 1):

Just using includes on your association will not load the association data in the json.

You will have to do

```
@e.users.as_json(include: :posts)
```

This will render the posts in the json data

Comment: You rocks with answer @Moiz Mansur . Thank you

Comment: Hi `@e.users.as_json(include: :posts)` , this step giving n+1 query problem. Is there any other way to do this with N+1 query problem?

Comment: Can you post what query you're getting here.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Like am sending only wanted columns data by pushing into new hash variable. So like that i controlled the N+1 query problem.

Comment: Might want  to answer this question with your solution in case anyone else faces the same kind of problem